# Is it possible to skip prepend_before_action in Rails 4 and Devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I want to enforce authentication to Devise registration controller's `new` and `create` function because I am implementing a custom sign_up mechanism that requires an admin to sign in first.

But Devise is forcing `require_no_authentication` on `new` and `create` with `prepend_before_action`.

According to Rails, I can `skip_before_action`, however,

**how do I force skipping `prepend_before_action`?**

Comment: I don't think this will work as intended even if you get this skipping the `before_action` - if you want admins to create new user records, the typical approach is to build an admin area and normal CRUD interface for managing them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Doesn't `skip_before_action` work for you? A `before_action` is just an [alias for `append_before_action`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/AbstractController/Callbacks/ClassMethods.html#method-i-before_action) and I think it does not matter whether the callback is appended or prepended to the list of callbacks to be allowed to be skipped with `skip_before_action`.

Comment: [Here is the actual line](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/a690207700d92a1e24712c95114a2931d6197985/actionpack/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb#L219-L220) in the Rails source code that defines this, for the curious.